# two types on same input field grapqhql lighthouse

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

So how can I do, or is possible to have 2 types on the input fields?
For example, I have like:

```
input UpdatePersonInput {
    first_name: String
    surname: String
    age: Int
}

extend type Mutation {
    updatePerson(id: ID!, input: UpdatePersonInput!): Person! @field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Mutations\\Person@update")
}
```

On my input, I want a type **Int** but at the same time want the type **null** (this type don't exist by my knowledge) to update on DB the field age on Persons (like some people give age and some don't).
This is a simple example, but my code is more complex and I can't be checking if the key comes or not in the input like

```
key_exists('age', $args['input'])
```

on the resolver method update.
I am using lighthouse graphql v4.16.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use [`Arr::get($args, 'age')`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Arr.html#method_get)

Comment: I want the client be able to send me type `null` and I don't want validations on, to see if it exists or not in the array of args like I did it but with php.
Example:
`$args = [
'first_name' => 'francisco',
'surname' => 'caldeira',
'age' => **null**
]`

or this way,

`$args = [
'first_name' => 'francisco',
'surname' => 'caldeira',
'age' => **24**
]`

@enzo-notario

Comment: Yes, you are using just `Int`, not `Int!` (note the `!`). So you should be able to pass `null` as value.